# Delete item from a subcollection in firebase with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I made the subcollection 'medicine" from the collection 'users', im trying to delete each item from that subcollection when clicking a button, this is what i did:

```
import {auth, db} from "../../firebase/firebase.config";
import {doc, deleteDoc} from "firebase/firestore";

function BotonEliminar(id) {

    const user = auth?.currentUser?.uid;

    const deleteElement = async () =>{
       await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'users', user, 'medicine', id));
        
    }

.... etc
```

I got in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function

I don't know what I doing wrong. I get the id and the user correctly.

---

Doing the `console.log(db, user, id);`

[image]

How the database looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you try `console.log(db, user, id)` in that function and share the output?

Comment: Yes, of course! I add the captures on top

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that `id` is an Object, not a String. (From the console screenshot, it looks like `{id: 'liKQ1I0RjliCQVKFHvc'}` rather than just `'liKQ1I0RjliCQVKFHvc'`)

Assuming that `BotonEliminar` is meant to be a React component, the argument is a React props object rather than the actual id. You probably want to change the function signature to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the id from the props:

```js
function BotonEliminar({id}) { // note the { and }
```

and then use `id` normally.